# ambassador edge stack mapping is not working

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service, ambassador

I am trying to set up the ambassador edge stack in my local Kubernetes (Docker Desktop cluster).

After all deployment, I checked the ambassador namespace and everything is working as expected. Moreover, I have my deployment (pod and services) working.I have changed the ambassador edge-stack service to nodeport so I can access and test locally. also, I have added the url in my HOST file.

Now, Here is the detail.

```
kubectl get svc -n ambassador
```

[image]

```
kubectl get svc -n sample-on-ambassador-edgestack
```

[image]

```
edgestack-listener yaml:
--------------------------
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v3alpha1
kind: Listener
metadata:
  name: my-listener-80
  namespace: sample-on-ambassador-edgestack
spec:
  port: 80
  protocol: HTTP
  securityModel: XFP
  hostBinding: 
    namespace:
      from: ALL


apiVersion: getambassador.io/v3alpha1
kind: Listener
metadata:
  name: my-listener-8080
  namespace: sample-on-ambassador-edgestack
spec:
  port: 8080
  protocol: HTTP
  securityModel: XFP
  hostBinding: 
    namespace:
      from: ALL


edgestack-binding yaml
-------------------------
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v3alpha1
kind: Mapping
metadata:
  name: my-mappingrules
  namespace: sample-on-ambassador-edgestack
spec:
  hostname: "local.edgestack.com"
  prefix: /apple/
  service: my-apple-service.sample-on-ambassador-edgestack
```

***NOTE: I have used Service: pod.service form above***.

With this, I am getting edgestack home page with http://local.edgestack.com
[image]

but If I type: local.edgestack.com/apple/ I am getting 404 error page.
same with curl comamnd:

```html
curl -i http://local.edgestack.com:32510/apple/


HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
date: Thu, 02 Dec 2021 01:51:48 GMT
server: envoy
content-length: 0
```

Comment: I also check exec --it -- sh command on ambassador pod and try curl  my-apple-service.sample-on-ambassador-edgestack and it gives the correct result. that means the service is reachable from the ambassador pod without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has nothing to do with namespacing but rather is that you are accessing the service on a `NodePort` and are therefore including the port in the host of your curl request but not configuring Emissary to account for that.

If you were to send a curl with the `-v` flag set, you would see that this request has `> Host: local.edgestack.com:32510` which is not the same as `local.edgestack.com` which your Emissary Ingress is expecting. Since the hostname of the incoming request does not match the `Mapping.spec.hostname` you have configured, Emissary is not finding a matching route and returning a 404.

You can get around this by doing a glob in the `Mapping.spec.hostname` so that it matches `local.edgestack.com` and any ports that follow

```
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v3alpha1
kind: Mapping
metadata:
  name: my-mappingrules
  namespace: sample-on-ambassador-edgestack
spec:
  hostname: "local.edgestack.com*"
  prefix: /apple/
  service: my-apple-service
```

Comment: Hi Noah, Thanks for pointing out that specific mapping (*) missing in hostname as I am using hostname with port in curl and URL. I have corrected that in Mapping yaml and redeployed it. However, the result is not as expected. instead of 404 it gives 301 (Moved permanently) it moves the http://... to https://... and gives no result. going to give you more detail in slack